# Monotone function and inverse function

Tags: limits, functions, inverse-function, monotone-functions

Show that the function $y= f(x)= 1+ x^{2} + \arctan x^{2}$ is strictly monotone in $[0,+\infty ]$. If $f^{-1}$ is the reverse function of $f$, calculate the limit $$\lim_{y\rightarrow 1+}\frac{f^{-1}(y)}{\sqrt{y-1}}$$

I calculated the derivative of $f$ and I noticed that $f' > 0$ for every $x$ in $[0,+\infty ]$, so $f$ is strictly increasing.

But I have difficulties calculating the limit.

Comment: The usual terminology is “inverse function”, rather than “reverse function”.

Comment: What is the value of $f(0)$? Of $f^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: Have you studied L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales  $f(0)=1$ so $f^{-1}(f(0))=f^{-1}(1)$. So I got $f^{-1}(1)=0$. I had found that I had to use L'Hopital's rule but I couldn't solve it.